# No Audio (Ubuntu 16.04.1 on NUC)

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hda-intel, intel-nuc

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04.1 on my Intel NUC5CPYH with Celeron N3050 processor. Now there is no sound output, neither over HDMI nor over the analog jack. The system settings and pavucontrol show up a "dummy device", alsamixer even doesn't start up because there was no device found.

```
cat /proc/asound/cards
--- no soundcards ---
```

`lspci -nn | grep Audio` returns blank, output of `lspci -nn` here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23407703/

What can I do to get that working? Which additional debug info should I post?

Comment: Can you add the output of `lspci -nn | grep Audio` please? If it returns blank, then please include the output of `lspci -nn`.

Answer (score 1):

From [Intel](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/boards-and-kits/000005499.html) Linux support, you must install latest Alsa driver for Ubuntu. In a terminal window, run the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev/alsa-daily
sudo apt update
sudo apt install oem-audio-hda-daily-dkms
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Thanks, but the solution was a bit easier: the internal sound was disabled in BIOS (whyever). After enabling it even worked with the default Alsa driver.

Comment: I got the following error after apt install: Error!  The dkms.conf for this module includes a BUILD_EXCLUSIVE directive which
does not match this kernel/arch.  This indicates that it should not be built.
Done.