# Dummy output, no audio

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I've spent the past 2-3 hours attempting to fix my audio by browsing the forum and google to no avail. I have an asus r556la running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Have installed pulse audio. Attempted installing OSS (to find out it's no longer supported). Tried multiple updates. Attempted to install realtek audio driver, which would also no install due to invalid instructions. I'm seeing dummy output and no audio cards detected. I have a dual boot and my audio works perfectly fine on windows so I know my hardware works. Trying to learn ubuntu but still new to it.

Comment: aplay -l   (in a terminal) will show if Alsa see any audio card.   Another point : Sometimes it is usefull to do a real shutdown from Windows , wait and start Linux.

Comment: I did the shutdown from windows and started Linux to test my audio on that side to ensure there were no hardware issues. I'll try the aplay -l but the other commands I've tried showed 0 cards however.

Comment: In case of driver issue, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/843475/no-audio-ubuntu-16-04-1-on-nuc/844288#844288   : this is for installing latest Alsa driver from Ubuntu packages (not from Realtek where Linux drivers are outdated)

Comment: I was facing the same problem and it solved using the following commands 1. `killall pulseaudio; rm -r ~/.config/pulse/* ; rm -r ~/.pulse*; ~/.config/pulse`, 2. `pulseaudio -k `